# MySQL report query optimization and timezone issues

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, reporting, timezone-offset

I'm faced with a MySQL database which contains an `events` table with ~70 million rows which has foreign keys to other tables and is used to generate reports. Constructing a performant query to select (while counting/summing values) and grouping data per day from this table is proving challenging.

The database structure is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_client_id_name` (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_client_id_idx` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_client_id` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3


CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `venue_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_class_id_idx` (`class_id`),
  KEY `fk_venue_id_idx` (`venue_id`),
  KEY `idx_1` (`venue_id`,`class_id`,`start_time`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_class_id` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_venue_id` FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`) REFERENCES `venue` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64093231 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

CREATE TABLE `venue` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_venue_id_name` (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

The query which is fine on an `events` table with a few thousand rows to demonstrate the desired outcome is as follows:

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST(event.start_time as date) as day,
    class.name,
    client.name,
    venue.name,
    COUNT(class.name) AS occurrences,
    SUM(class.duration) AS duration
FROM
    class,
    client,
    event,
    venue
WHERE
    event.venue_id = venue.id
    AND event.class_id = class.id
    AND class.client_id = client.id
GROUP BY day, class.name, client.name, venue.name
```

The database isn't indexed and although I've tried indexing with things like `alter table events add index idx_test (venue_id, class_id, start_time);` to improve performance it's still incredibly slow (I tend to abort them when they're past the 10 minute mark so don't know for sure how long they'd take to complete).

I figured this was a good use case for a summary table (as suggested by [Rick James' guide](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)) so that I could hold a separate set of summarized data broken down into day with occurrences and total duration calculated/incremented with each addition to the table (IODKU). However I'm then also up against creating rows per day in a summary table based on what is considered a day in the database (UTC) which may not match with the application's "day" due to timezone offset.
Short of converting the `start_time` column to a `timestamp` type (which is then inconsistent with all other date types in the database) is there any way round this or is there any other optimization I could be making to the original `events` table resulting in a more responsive query? TIA

### **Update 23/05**

Here's the buffer pool size:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

I've also made a bit of progress with indexing, modifying the query and creating a summary table.
I tried various ordering of columns to test indexes and found `idx_event_venueid_classid_starttime` (below), to be the most efficient for the `event` table:

```sql
SHOW INDEXES FROM EVENT;
+-------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| event |          0 | PRIMARY                             |            1 | id          | A         |    62142912 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| event |          1 | fk_class_id_idx                     |            1 | class_id    | A         |       51286 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| event |          1 | fk_venue_id_idx                     |            1 | venue_id    | A         |       16275 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| event |          1 | idx_event_venueid_classid_starttime |            1 | venue_id    | A         |       13378 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| event |          1 | idx_event_venueid_classid_starttime |            2 | class_id    | A         |       81331 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| event |          1 | idx_event_venueid_classid_starttime |            3 | start_time  | A         |    63909472 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Here's my modified version of the query, using `JOIN` syntax and now uses `CONVERT_TZ` to convert from UTC to the timezone required for reporting and then group that by the date (discarding the time portion):

```sql
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(event.start_time,
    'UTC',
    'Europe/London')) AS tz_date,
  class.name,
  client.name,
  venue.name,
  COUNT(class.id) AS occurrences,
  SUM(class.duration) AS duration
FROM
  event
JOIN
  class ON class.id = event.class_id
JOIN
  venue ON venue.id = event.venue_id
JOIN
  client ON client.id = class.client_id
GROUP BY tz_date, class.name, client.name, venue.name;
```

And here's the output of `explain` for that query:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                       | key                                 | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | venue  | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,idx_venue_id_name                                           | idx_venue_id_name                   | 772     | NULL                    |   28 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | event  | NULL       | ref    | fk_class_id_idx,fk_venue_id_idx,idx_event_venueid_classid_starttime | idx_event_venueid_classid_starttime | 5       | example.venue.id        | 4777 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | class  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fk_client_id_idx                                            | PRIMARY                             | 4       | example.event.class_id  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | client | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_client_id_name                                          | PRIMARY                             | 4       | example.class.client_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                         |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

The query takes ~1m 20s to run now so I figured I could prepend that with an `insert into` to populate a summary table with the dates being timezone specific and run that on a nightly basis. Summary table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `summary` (
  `tz_date` date NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `client` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `venue` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `occurrences` int NOT NULL,
  `duration` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tz_date`,`class`,`client`,`venue`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

From the original ~60m+ rows in the event table, the aggregated summary table is populated with ~66k rows.
To then generate the reports from the summary table it takes a fraction of a second (shown below with data snipped):

```sql
SELECT * FROM SUMMARY;
66989 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I haven't looked into the impact of inserting into `event` while the query to populate the summary table is running - is using InnoDB likely to slow that down?

Comment: As you know, we prefer questions that address just one issue. To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then ask another question.  And, you may wish to ask a different [tag:timezone] question.

Comment: If you use TIMESTAMP data type, expect application failure on 2038-01-19 ( if you are still around) .  Search for mysql timestamp date range for the limits and AVOID using timestamp forever.

Comment: @WilsonHauck well yes, hence the DATETIME usage so far and desire to stick with it ideally...the only reason for mentioning TIMESTAMP is that it can be timezone aware

Comment: @gratz Could you post your small example EVENTS table and the other tables to allow quick testing?

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck I've updated the original question with an update and further information on the structure of the tables, not the data though

Comment: @gratz  Thanks for the additional info. Would it be helpful to know how to restrict the volume of data to a date range? Forever data ranges would seem to be overwhelming volume of information.

Comment: @WilsonHauck The summary table is relatively small now and it takes a fraction of a second to query all results from that table so for generating reports it'll be very responsive now.
In terms of data from the event table, I'll probably look to introduce a rolling window of data there, deleting anything older than X on a daily basis, or possibly archive it off into another table which should help I think...

Comment: What is current result of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'; ?

Comment: If you really need the data, keep it where it is.  Your life is complicated enough already.

Comment: True enough, thanks @WilsonHauck

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` = 134217728

Rick James' suggestion below is to up that to ~70% of available RAM

Comment: With 16GB you would do well to set ibps to 8G in your configuration and be close to Rick James's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks yeah, that's what I went with for now to see how it behaves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No further indexes are likely to help.  It need to scan all the `events` table, reaching into the other tables to get the names.

Some things for us to look at:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

How much RAM do you have?

Do the aggregates (`COUNT` and `SUM`) look correct?  In some situations involving `JOIN`, they can be over-inflated.

Please use the newer `JOIN ... ON` syntax.  (Won't change performance.)

As you observed, a Summary Table may help -- but only of the older data is not being modified.  Please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and query for it.

Yes, timezone vs "definition of day" is a thorny issue.  Notice how StackOverflow defines day based on UTC.

How many new rows are there per day?  Are they spread out somewhat evenly throughout the day?  If the average number of rows per hour is at least 20, then the Summary Table could be based on half-hour intervals.  (I picked that because of India time vs most of the rest of the world.)  The 20 comes from a Rule of Thumb that says that a summary table should have one-tenth as many rows as the Fact table.

Yes, `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME` *may* be a workaround.

Since you are talking about moderately large tables, consider whether to change `INT NULL` to `SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL` or some other sized integer.

(As for the cliff in 2038, ask yourself how many databases have been active on the same hardware and software since 2006.  That may give some perspective on whether your design must survive 16 years.)

Comment: Thanks! I've added an update above with more detail and the output of fetching the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, using `JOIN` syntax in the updated query. 

The amount of RAM could be different but I'm currently I'm running on a machine with 16GB

Can you think of any caveats to the CONVERT_TZ approach?

I think there's a few optimizations that could be made to columns in terms of storage allocation (INT where SMALLINT would be sufficient but plenty of others so I'll look at that too)

Comment: @gratz - 128M an old, inadequate, default for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Change it to about 70% of available RAM.